Не переопределяется абстрактный метод
Framework.h
#pragma once
#include "Windows.h"
#include "gdiplus.h"
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "GdiPlus.lib")

Resources.h
#pragma once
#include "Framework.h"

class Resources {

public:

    struct Dimensions {
        Gdiplus::REAL scale;
    };

    Resources(Gdiplus::REAL scale) {
        this->dimensions.scale = scale;
    }

    virtual ~Resources() {}

    Dimensions dimensions;

};

Application.h
#pragma once
#include "Framework.h"
#include "Resources.h"

template<class R>
class Application {

public:

    Application(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
        SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE);
        this->hInstance = hInstance;
        this->resources = NULL;
        CheckScale(GetDpiForSystem());
    }

    virtual ~Application() {
        if (this->resources) { delete this->resources; }
    }

    R* GetResources() { return this->resources; }

    VOID CheckScale(UINT dpi) {
        Gdiplus::REAL newScale = (Gdiplus::REAL)dpi / (Gdiplus::REAL)USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;
        if (!this->resources || ((Resources*)this->resources)->dimensions.scale != newScale) {
            if (this->resources) { delete this->resources; }
            this->resources = OnCreateResources(newScale);
        }
    }

protected:

    virtual R* OnCreateResources(Gdiplus::REAL scale) abstract;

private:

    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    R* resources;

};

Backuper_Resources.h
#pragma once
#include "Framework.h"
#include "Resources.h"

class Backuper_Resources : public Resources {

public:

    static Backuper_Resources* Create(Gdiplus::REAL scale) {
        if (scale >= 1.0F) { return new Backuper_Resources(scale); }
        return NULL;
    }

    virtual ~Backuper_Resources() {}

private:

    Backuper_Resources(Gdiplus::REAL scale) : Resources(scale) {}

};

Backuper_Application.h
#pragma once
#include "Framework.h"
#include "Application.h"
#include "Backuper_Resources.h"

class Backuper_Application : public Application<Backuper_Resources> {

public:

    Backuper_Application(HINSTANCE hInstance) : Application<Backuper_Resources>(hInstance) {}

    virtual ~Backuper_Application() {}

protected:

    virtual Backuper_Resources* OnCreateResources(Gdiplus::REAL scale) override {
        Backuper_Resources* resources = Backuper_Resources::Create(scale);
        if (!resources) {
            throw std::exception("resources == NULL");
        }
        return resources;
    }

};

Main.cpp
#include "Framework.h"
#include "Backuper_Application.h"



INT WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR pCmdLine, _In_ INT nCmdShow) {
    // Запуск GDI+
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Backuper_Application* application = new Backuper_Application(hInstance);

    if (!application->GetResources()) { OutputDebugStringW(L"resources == NULL\n"); }
    
    delete application;

    // Завершение GDI+
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}

Процесс крашится на строке класса "Application" this->resources = OnCreateResources(newScale); с сообщением "abort() has been called", и до переопределенного метода класса "Backuper_Application" дело не доходит.
Если я в классе "Application" сделаю метод не абстрактным
virtual R* OnCreateResources(Gdiplus::REAL scale) { return NULL; }

то приложение не крашится, но "this->resources" класса "Application" всегда будет равен NULL, и до переопределённого метода класса "Backuper_Application" всё равно дело не доходит.
В чём собственно проблема не могу понять?

Ваш код невозможно скомпилировать, так как используются странные макроподстановки и использование сущностей, которые не описаны. Сделайте минималистичный пример, воспроизводящий ошибку.

Заголовок вопроса не соответствует описанию. [mcve] не приведен. Поле Application::resources не инициализировано. Передача сырых указателей со владением.

Извините, добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Похоже на то, что вы не стоставили [mcve], а просто вывалили сюда весь свой код... В конструкторе нельзя вызывать вирутальные методы.
